# Java - Passing a Symbolic Class Object to a Method

Tags: java

I am writing a generic method that will set a specific object of a class. Say I have this:

```
public class MyRecord {
    public String name;
    public String comment;
}
```

In my method I will pass an instance of MyRecord to the constructor and keep it:

```
public class Processor {
    private MyRecord rec;
    public Processor(MyRecord rec_) {
        rec=rec_;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    public void doIt(Object object_) {
        rec.object_=<Something>;
    }
}
```

When I call doIt, I want to pass which object of MyRecord to set in the method. I know I can do a different method for each element but that is not my question. Is this or something similar possible and if so how? Maybe what I am looking for is a way to emulate pass by reference. TIA.

Comment: Please edit your question to show a full example on how you want to use the `MyRecord` and `Processor` class. The example should show what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do exactly what you asked by using introspection and reflexion :

```
public void doIt(Field f, Object value) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{
    f.set(rec, value);
}
```

Where `f` should be something like `MyRecord.class.getField("name")`.

You can see it in action [here](https://ideone.com/yTXshc).

That sounds like a bad idea in general, maybe unless you're dealing with classes with hundreds of fields you can't refactor and have to populate.